# What file-types have supported playback by Naudio-library C#

Tags: c#, naudio, file-type

I've been trying to find which audioformats are supported by default in the Naudio library for c#, with no luck.

I've read that MP3, WAV, WMA, OGG and FLAC is supported.

Is this correct? And is there any more audiotypes available?

Answer (score 4):

By default NAudio reads WAV, AIFF, MP3 and (generally, depending on your OS config) WMA.  Other formats may be supported through Media Foundation - anything it can read, NAudio supports.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists the various file formats and codecs supported by Windows Media Foundation.  It's a fairly long list.